# Rstudio fails to be displayed on my laptop (client) when trying to X11 forwarding from my Imac (server) at home

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, forwarding, rstudio

I am trying to display Rstudio on my laptop (where I have Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS) using X11 forwarding with ssh to connect to my Imac at home.

I set up all the files (ssh_config and sshd_config) on my Imac (which I am using as a server) to allow the forwarding. I also install xauth on my Imac. However, when I connect to my Imac using `ssh -X username@IPAddress` and launch Rstudio with `open -a Rstudio`, Rstudio opens on my Imac but its not displayed on my laptop.

However, if I launch `xterm`, a window opens up on my laptop, making me think that the connection I set up is correct. I also tried to reverse the process, which means I tried to ssh into my laptop (in this case used as server) using my Imac and launch `firefox`, in this case the firefox window is displayed correctly on my Imac.

What am I missing when I try to display Rstudio on my laptop?

Thank you for your help.

Riccardo

Comment: Is the version of Rstudio you're using an X11 version? The default macOS version from rstudio.com is not, so you can't forward it.

Comment: Thank you @Wieland for your responce. I don't know how to check for that but it might be that you are totally right. How did you know that Rstudio for macOS does not support forward? Do you think that using Rstudio server might solve my problem? Do you think I should directly ask on rstudio.com? Thank you again!

Comment: I checked the source code - Rstudio is built with the Qt framework, which uses the platforms native toolkit for building the UI. X11 is not used on macOS, you even have to install xquartz to get things like xauth onto the system. So no, Rstudio on macOS does not support X11 forwarding. I do not know anything about Rstudio server.